# Python list extend with random elements keeping boundaries/raw

Tags: python, list, random, floating

I am trying to find a way to extent a list with random floating numbers, keeping all the elements in the same order; the first and the last in the same position. But, I need these numbers to have an analogue increasing.

What I mean:
e.g. : if `A == [1.3, 4.5, 6.8, 9.6, 11.3]`

I would like the new list to become something like this:

```
B = [1.3, 2.3, 4.5, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8, 9.6, 10.4, 11.1, 11.3]
```

So the 5 elements to become 11 (or anything else) and the new list to obtain random elements between (or not) each initial element (without that to be necessary -6.8, 9.6-).

Is it this possible? Do I am asking too much?

Thank you

Comment: There is nothing random about this, so why did you tag it with random? Is there something missing that I didn't get?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The new values inserted in between each of the original items are "random" - just a random number between the lower and higher item. (i think)

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
num_elems_to_add = 10
A=[1.3, 4.5, 6.8, 9.6, 11.3]
new_elems = [random.uniform(A[0],A[-1]) for _ in range(num_elems_to_add)]
print sorted(A+new_elems)
```

is that what you wanted?

Comment: I think the `new_elems` isn't known, and needs to be generated based on `A`

Comment: no ... it was just an example ... the A list have at least 100 elements. I want to have a new list, with 200 elements keeping the first and the last element in the same position, and of course the other 98. Now, for the other 100 elements I would like these to be generated randomly but keeping the same increasing order...

Comment: Again, I don't think `num_elems_to_add` should be set either. It is based on the length of `A`. If `A` has 9 items, `new_elems` should end up having 8, and obviously the returned array have 17.

Comment: in his example he has 5 and adds 6 ... but he does not imply a correlation between the two at least not that i read... so based on his example if A was 9 ... new_elems would be 10 and total new size 19 ... but again i dont think there is necessarily a correlation ...

Comment: Sorry, guess I misread that, you're right. I guess I wouldn't know what to do to determine the total number of new items to add...I just didn't think it should be fixed.

Comment: I agree... but he can get num_elements_to_add however he wants... (fileIO,based on size of A,userIO,etc.)...

Answer (score 1):

there may be a more efficient method, but this works fine:

```
  import random

  A = [1.3, 4.5, 6.8, 9.6, 11.3]
  low = A[0]
  high = A[-1]
  B = []
  for i in range(10):
      B.append(random.uniform(low,high))
  B.extend(A)
  B.sort()
```

Comment: Its best to recreate a new list as inserting operations in lists is expensive, if your list gets very big.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- thanks.  Would substituting for the "for" loop something like `B = [random.uniform(low,high) for i in range(10)]` be more efficient?

Comment: Yes you can do that - I believe it will be less expensive than extending the list. You can also step through the list by twos and then insert any missing gaps; that way you don't have to extend the original.